# How to align element horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue in my case

I have something like

```
<div class='test'>
    <button class='btn'></button>
   <div class='nest'>
      more...
   </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.test{
   z-index: 100;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   left: 1%;
   width: 98%;
   min-width: 500px;
   height: 45px;
   background: url(images/botnav_bg_shim.png) repeat-x;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn{
   margin-left: 2px;
   width: 128px;
   height: 48px; 
   background:url(images/bot.png) no-repeat;
}

.nest{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 10px;
   height: 45px;
   padding-left: 17px; 
   background:url(images/nest.png) no-repeat;
}
```

My problem is my button element will be forced to shifted down for like 50px for no reason. Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Two of your background urls are missing opening quotes. I'd start by fixing that.

Comment: thanks i just fixed the typo. still need help :(

Comment: check this out and see if it of help http://jsfiddle.net/ZcAPX/

Comment: @Adrift You can use the url with or without quotes, but that wasn't the issue. He had a quote terminating the string but not one in the beginning. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

delete or add comment blocks ( /* ... */ ) to

```
position: absolute;
```

in **.test** class